# Moto X is not recognized on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, usb, adb

Ubuntu won't recognize my phone. 
It isn't even listed in lsusb output:
`darlan@HTPC ~ $ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 045e:0745 Microsoft Corp. Nano Transceiver v1.0 for Bluetooth
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub`

Tried adding a rule to udev, with no success, as follows 
`darlan@HTPC ~ $ cat /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="22b8", MODE="0666"`

Using adb tools with root permission also doesn't work 
`darlan@HTPC ~/dev/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140321/sdk/platform-tools $ sudo ./adb devices
List of devices attached`

Could anyone shed some light on the matter? My kernel version is 3.13.0-24-generic, and I would gladly provide more information.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Please read the 3rd point in the **Setting up a device for development**.

http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html#setting-up

That worked in my case.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Yes sure. To avoid any future problem I just created a blog entry after I successfully connected my device with the system.

http://ravinishad.blogspot.in/2015/01/enable-detection-of-usb-devices-on.html

Also attached the sample rules file in the blog entry. 
Please check it and let me know if there is any issue as I am new to Ubuntu.

Comment: Like I posted earlier. It's nice to link from where you have gathered your information but [it would be better](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259) if you would include the main steps in your answer. [Click on the edit-link](http://askubuntu.com/posts/573971/edit) below your answer to include those essential parts.

Answer (score 0):

Suffered the same problem a while back. The solution is you need to install `mtp tools`. 
Try this, i am pretty sure this will work fine:-

```
sudo apt-get install mtp-tools mtpfs
```

Then, make sure the when u plug in ur phone, MTP mode is enabled

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have the developer options turned on. Once you turn that off there is a chance that your phone will be detected on Ubuntu. I don't why that happens, but that was the issue with my phone. I had two Moto E phones and one of them was detected on my Xubuntu while the other doesn't. And that's how i came across this. Also i do have the 
vendor ID in 51 rules file.

SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="22b8", MODE="0666",

OS: Xubuntu 14.04
3.18 rc4 Kernel.